# SSRS sort columns

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have some data which looks like this

```
ID   |Name  | Label1| Data1 |L2 |D2 |L3 | D3|
AAAA | C    | X     | 2     | Y | 4 |   |   |
BBBB | D    | Y     | 5     | Z | 6 |   |   | 
CCCC | E    | X     | 3     | Y | 6 | Z | 9 |
DDDD | F    | Z     | 5     | X | 6 | Y | 3 |
```

And I need to display it on a report like so:

```
ID   |Name  | X | Y | Z | 
AAAA | C    | 2 | 4 | 0 |
BBBB | D    | 0 | 5 | 6 |
CCCC | E    | 3 | 6 | 9 |
DDDD | F    | 6 | 3 | 5 |
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand how your data is structured. Have you tried using a column group on your label column?

Comment: I am not sure how to use column groups at all.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149.aspx

Comment: My data labels are not nicely sorted though, so I'm kinda not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pivot the data in SQL:

```
-- load test data
declare @YourTable table(ID char(4),Name char(1),L1 char(1),D1 int,L2 char(1),D2 int,L3 char(1),D3 int)
insert into @YourTable values
    ('AAAA','C','X',2,'Y',4,null,null),
    ('BBBB','D','Y',5,'Z',6,null,null),
    ('CCCC','E','X',3,'Y',6,'Z',9),
    ('DDDD','F','Z',5,'X',6,'Y',3)

-- return pivoted data
select
    ID,
    Name,
    isnull([X],0) [X],
    isnull([Y],0) [Y],
    isnull([Z],0) [Z]
from    (
        select
            yt.ID,
            yt.Name,
            ld.Label,
            ld.Data
        from @YourTable yt
            cross apply (
                        select L1 Label,D1 Data union all
                        select L2 Label,D2 Data union all
                        select L3 Label,D3 Data
                        ) ld
        ) t
    pivot   (
            max(Data)
            for Label in([X],[Y],[Z])
            ) p
```

Comment: Might work. I was trying to find a more efficient method than Pivoting the table 3 times and Union and then Group.

Comment: BTW, is there a way to select all distinct label names from all 3 columns to go with it? Cause it might be all letters of the alphabet.